# How to choose the right database for historic data storage for small company

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, postgresql, nosql

I am working on creating a new database to store all the JSON file we accumulated historically (not much data, in the range of 10s of GB). We are a really small company and this database will be used internally primarily for reading purposes. I am struggling with which database to choose from - MongoDB, DynamoDB, Cassandra, MySQL, Postgres, HBase etc. I am thinking of going for NoSQL based database because seems more flexible. The idea is to have a storage from where anyone in our company can query and get the data (present in JSON files) and perform their analysis subsequently.

Comment: If you need "...anyone in our company..." to query the data, maybe you need to also focus on the GUI tools that will allow them to access, filter, and aggregate the data.

Comment: Saving JSON almost demands NoSQL, however if the data isn't organised (i.e. Indexable), then you might as well fragment it out and store it in Amazon S3 or some similar flat storage to download and analyse locally.

Comment: @TheImpaler You are correct that I might need a visual interface in a long run to give better accessibility to my team, but right now I just want to have a DB running so that they can use the data.

Comment: Sure @cYrixmorten but flat files storage systems might require some redundant work every time someone wants to get specific info from data. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If searching content within the json is key, then perhaps elasticsearch makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern relational databases (MySQL, Postgres) support "JSON" columns, so if your data does not have a known fixed schema, they are a viable option too. Similarly, modern NoSQL databases such as MongoDB have added traditional SQL features such as transactions. So the distinction blurs.

To determine what database fits your needs, you need to think about how the data is accessed:

- Do you need efficient updating of records (and if so, are transactions needed), or just want to add new ones?
- Do you need to fetch specific records by some key or process lots of records to summarize data (the latter is called "analytical processing")
- Do you expect to have multiple tables with queries joining data between them? (it sounds like you currently don't need this, but it pays to think about the future when it comes to databases)

If updating is not needed and you need to aggregate many records, you can use something like AWS Athena / Presto / Drill to query plain files stored on a local server or on something like AWS S3.

Cassandra and HBase are specialized databases that are highly scalable and sacrifice some functionality for that scalability. Seems inappropriate for such a small database.

MongoDB is easy to manage and horizontally scalable but has some limitations, given its NoSQL heritage.

MySQL/Postgres are both easy to manage and will easily handle 10s of GBs. Postgres is somewhat more sophisticated and capable when it comes to analytical processing. MySQL is easier to manage and very performant when it comes to "transaction processing" -- that is, updating and querying specific records (when you have an index quickly leading you to the wanted records)